# Startup errors are swallowed, how to see them?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-front-door

We have an Azure Function 2.x running on consumption with FrontDoor in ... front.
So it looks like this.

```
                 [Azure Function East 2.x Consumption]     
[FrontDoor] - < 
                 [Azure Function West 2.x Consumption]
```

We have Azure Monitor configured to send us an Alert anytime Response code 5xx is thrown on the azure function.

- Since putting Front Door in place, we have been getting 5xx alerts several times a day.
- These 5xx are not making into Application Insights.
- Nothing in Log analytics about a failure.

Historically we know this can happen when an Azure Function has a Startup failure. However, looking through logs in Kudu, we dont see any startup failures.

We do see alot of entries where the function run time is starting and stopping, as we would expect to see on a consumption plan function.

SO. We think that these 5xx errors are being caused by Front Door sending a health check to the function when it is starting up. (Front Door is very chatty on health checks)
But we cant prove this b/c the Azure Function Runtime provides 0 insight into startup failures.

**Question**
How can I see Azure Function Runtime startup failures?

Triggered Alert Rule:
[image]

Comment: Nothing in eventlog.xml in kudu? That’s often where hard to diagnose startup issues show.

Comment: Correct. I can see msgs indicating a PID exited and a new PID started that correlates to these issues, however we dont have any associated error msgs. Just pid died pid created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume if you invoke the function and it provides the expected response, it proves it's not a startup problem.

What can be the reason is 502 errors which are not captured by Application Insights since they happen at IIS level (most of the time).

I've noticed several 502 on my Azure Functions latetly, but they were related to long running tasks / timeouts.

Take a look on Diagnostic tools / Availability and Performance / 5xx Errors. It should give you some direction on what is the problem. Here's a sample from one of my projects that I was facing several 502 errors:

[image]

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-azure-app-service